# How to hide URL parameters in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to hide or remove URL parameters in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

**Example action link**

```
<a asp-controller="Example" asp-action="Test" asp-route-entityid="@Model.EntityID">Entity</a>
```

**Result**
https://localhost:44352/Example/Test?entityid=Entity

**Desired result**
https://localhost:44352/Example/Test

Comment: What is the purpose of doing it?

Comment: Hi @crayden, any updates about this case? If the answer did help achieve your requirement, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @FeiHan was hoping to find a solution on the server. The answer below is on the client (JavaScript). Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the default behavior of the tag and when clicked on it send the request, but! pass the parameters as the body/data instead of the URL query

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

The [Anchor Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0) would be rendered as HTML anchor `<a ... ></a>` tag, normally it would help pass data through querystring or route data.

To achieve your requirement of hiding or removing URL parameter, you can try following workaround using form and hidden field to post data.

```
<form id="form1" asp-controller="Example" asp-action="Test" >
    <input type="hidden" name="entityid" value="123" />
    <a id="a_formpost" asp-controller="Example" asp-action="Test">Entity</a>
</form>
```

Trigger form submission while click `<a>` tag

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#a_formpost").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#form1").submit();
        })
    })
</script>
```